# Is there a more accurate LWJGL timer

Tags: java, lwjgl, timedelta, delta

After looking at timer showed on the LWJGL wiki milliseconds weren't fast enough. It kept an inconsistent speed of the player. I can't find anything on how to produce a more accurate timer, like 3.2 milliseconds instead of 3 milliseconds. I know this sounds stupid, but I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use System.nanoTime():

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();    
//Stuff in-between
long timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```